# ASP .NET Button event handlers do not fire on the first click, but on the second click after a PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

**Background:** I am customizing an existing ASP .NET / C# application. It has it's own little "framework" and conventions for developers to follow when extending/customizing its functionality. I am currently extending some of it's administrative functionality, to which the framework provides a contract to enforce implementation of the `GetAdministrationInterface()` method, which returns `System.Web.UI.Control`. This method is called during the `Page_Load()` method of the page hosting the GUI interface.

**Problem:** I have three buttons in my GUI, each of which have been assigned an Event Handler. My administration GUI loads up perfectly fine, but clicking any of the buttons doesn't do what I expect them to do. However, when I click them a second time, the buttons work.

I placed breakpoints at the beginning of each event handler method and stepped through my code. On the first click, none of the event handlers were triggered. On the second click, they fired.

Any ideas?

**Example of Button Definition (within `GetAdministrationInterface`)**

```
public override Control GetAdministrationInterface()
{
    // more code...

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Text = "Click Me!";
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(Btn_Click);

    // more code...
}
```

**Example of Event Handler Method Definition**

```
void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do Something
}
```

**`Page_Load` Method that calls `GetAdministrationInterface`**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsAsync)
    {
        List<AdministrationInterface> interfaces = <DATABASE CALL>;
        foreach(AdministrationInteface ai in interfaces)
        {
            placeholderDiv.Controls.Add(ai.GetAdministrationInterface());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you place your button definition and the event handler? How are the buttons being added to the page?

Comment: Post the Page_Load code that calls `GetAdminInterface` and builds the controls

Comment: I added the `Page_Load` code to the original question.

Comment: Is this a copy and paste? Because if it is, you are registering bth's click event and not btn's. Also, did you put a breakpoint in your code to make sure that the section is * actually* getting called?

Comment: For the record, "btn.Click += Btn_Click;" works just as well as "btn.Click += new EventHandler(Btn_Click);"

Comment: Sorry, I noticed the typo in my code as well. It wasn't a copy and paste. I typed up a simplified version of what's going on. I think I've fixed all the typos.

Thanks for the tip about assigning event handlers. I'll try that out and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Out of paranoia, I put an breakpoint beside each event handler assignment and within each event handler method, just to be sure. When the page loads, the event handler assignment code is called, as expected. When I click any of the buttons however, the event handler methods are *not* called. The page simply posts back. But now the strange part is when I click the buttons after this post back, the event handler methods are called...

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Good grief! I knew it was going to be something this stupid. Purely my fault of course and my lack of knowledge in ASP .NET.

After doing a multitude of Google searches and eventually being blocked by Google on suspicion of being a bot running automated scripts, I managed to squeeze in one last search in and stumbled across this [article](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Dynamically_Created_Controls_in_ASPNET.aspx). Already at the point of giving up, I tried my best to read the article without skipping 10 lines at a time or looking for pretty pictures. In the section titled *Assigning IDs to Dynamically Created Controls*, I read these magical and most joyful words:

> If you view the source HTML before you click the not-working button and after you have clicked it, you will notice a small difference. The buttons have different HTML IDs before and after the post-back. I got ctl04 and ctl05 before the post-back and ctl02 and ctl03 after the post-back.
>
> ASP.NET button recognizes events by checking for a value for its ID in the Request.Form collection. (In truth it happens differently and controls do not check Request.Form collection by themselves. Page passes post data to controls by their IDs and to controls that are registered to be notified about post data). ASP.NET does not fire the Click event, because the button's ID has changed between the post-backs. The button you have clicked and the button you see after are different buttons for ASP.NET.

Sure enough, when I viewed the HTML the first time, my button had the ID `ctl04$ctl36`. After clicking the button, my button had the ID `ctl04$ctl33`.

So there you have it! All I had to do was set the ID on the buttons and presto! My event handlers are now being called!

**Sample Solution:**

```
public override Control GetAdministrationInterface()
{
    // more code...

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Text = "Click Me!";
    // !!THE BANE OF MY EXISTENCE!!
    btn.ID = "The_Bane_of_My_Existence";
    // !!THE BANE OF MY EXISTENCE!!
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(Btn_Click);

    // more code...
}
```

What a great way to spend two days...

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem, but the accepted answer here was not causing it. I had a text box and a search button, and clicking the button the first time didn't perform the search. The event handler of the button wasn't being hit.  But clicking the button a second time did trigger the event on the server. Here is why:

If you have an `<asp:Textbox>` with its `AutoPostBack` set to `true`, after typing in the text box and then moving to click a button, the text box causes a post-back immediately the moment it loses focus. So the click even of the button doesn't count (the page is already posted-back as a result of the text box's event). That's why when you click the button a second time, it works because the text box is not involved in the second post-back.

Set the `AutoPostBack`property of the `<asp:Textbox>` to `false` to fix this issue.

Comment: Thank you! I checked my code and this was my problem too: I forgot to remove an AutoPostBack = true property of a text box's markup in the aspx page. I used it to debug some server-side validation code instead of doing client-side javascript. When I removed it, viola, the click event triggers every time I click the button. Now the button click event method can update the text box. Posting about the resolution of your own issue saved me hours of additional searching online for the issue. Grrr, I hate ASP.NET, but have to use it at work.

Answer (score 6):

A quick fix is to set an ID to the ASCX control your are loading on a page. For example, if your code is like this:

```
        UserControl SpecsControl = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl("../name.ascx");
        SpecsContainer.Controls.Add(SpecsControl);
```

then you need to add a line (before Controls.Add):

```
            SpecsControl.ID = "Aribtrary_Name";
```

Then your handler method is fired at the first click.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. My button froze after my first click. For me this annoying problem got solved when I disabled the button's `EnableViewState` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was the `UpdatePanel`  , my Button and my TextBox were both inside an `UpdatePanel` , so when I post-back , it caused some weird behavior . It took it outside of the `UpdatePanel` and that fixed it .

Answer (score 1):

Even i had the same problem. the cause was "localhost:1656/secure/login.aspx?**ReturnUrl=%2f**".
if the request contain **%2f** as query string, the first post will not be succeeded even though "**%2f**" is representing "**/**".

one way to avoid this by having a condition check in pageload

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string queryString = Request.QueryString.ToString();
    if(queryString == "ReturnUrl=%2f")
    {
        Response.Redirect("/secure/login.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst its hard to know exactly without seeing the full Page_load method it does smell a little bit like the event handlers are not hooking up until the page is reloaded.

eg:

```
if (IsPostBack) {
    // Add handlers here ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. And I searched on internet i didnt find a solution. After that i found sample code and I used it. It worked for me. Web site link is below:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/calling-an-Asp-Net-C-Sharp-method-web-method-using-javascript/