# Button click event not fired on first click

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, buttonclick

I have a project in which the event need to be fired on first click but the event is not getting fired on first click,it gets fired on second click but on first click postback do take place but event not getting fired

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_search" runat="server" Text="Search" CssClass="button blue"  onclick="btn_search_Click"  CausesValidation="False"/>
```

cs code for button click event

```
protected void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (txt_subcategory.Text.Length != 0 && txt_category.Text.Length == 0 && txt_author.Text.Length == 0 && txt_publisher.Text.Length == 0 && txt_isbn.Text.Length == 0 && txt_bookname.Text.Length == 0 && txt_edition.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        btnsearchsubcat();
        txt_subcategory.Text = "";

    }
    else if (txt_subcategory.Text.Length == 0 && txt_category.Text.Length != 0 && txt_author.Text.Length == 0 && txt_publisher.Text.Length == 0 && txt_isbn.Text.Length == 0 && txt_bookname.Text.Length == 0 && txt_edition.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        btnsearchcat();
        txt_category.Text = "";

    }
    else if (txt_subcategory.Text.Length == 0 && txt_category.Text.Length == 0 && txt_author.Text.Length != 0 && txt_publisher.Text.Length == 0 && txt_isbn.Text.Length == 0 && txt_bookname.Text.Length == 0 && txt_edition.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        btnsearchauthor();
        txt_author.Text = "";
    }
    else if (txt_subcategory.Text.Length == 0 && txt_category.Text.Length == 0 && txt_author.Text.Length == 0 && txt_publisher.Text.Length != 0 && txt_isbn.Text.Length == 0 && txt_bookname.Text.Length == 0 && txt_edition.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        btnsearchpublisher();
        txt_publisher.Text = "";
    }
    else if (txt_subcategory.Text.Length == 0 && txt_category.Text.Length == 0 && txt_author.Text.Length == 0 && txt_publisher.Text.Length == 0 && txt_isbn.Text.Length != 0 && txt_bookname.Text.Length == 0 && txt_edition.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        btnsearchisbn();
        txt_isbn.Text = "";
    }
    else if (txt_subcategory.Text.Length != 0 && txt_category.Text.Length == 0 && txt_author.Text.Length == 0 && txt_publisher.Text.Length == 0 && txt_isbn.Text.Length == 0 && txt_bookname.Text.Length != 0 && txt_edition.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        btnsearchname();
        txt_bookname.Text = "";
    }
    else if (txt_subcategory.Text.Length != 0 && txt_category.Text.Length != 0 && txt_author.Text.Length == 0 && txt_publisher.Text.Length == 0 && txt_isbn.Text.Length == 0 && txt_bookname.Text.Length == 0 && txt_edition.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        btnsearchcatsubcat();
    }
    else if (txt_subcategory.Text.Length != 0 && txt_category.Text.Length != 0 && txt_author.Text.Length != 0 && txt_publisher.Text.Length == 0 && txt_isbn.Text.Length == 0 && txt_bookname.Text.Length == 0 && txt_edition.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        btnsearchcatsubcatauthor();
    }
    else if (txt_subcategory.Text.Length == 0 && txt_category.Text.Length == 0 && txt_author.Text.Length == 0 && txt_publisher.Text.Length == 0 && txt_isbn.Text.Length == 0 && txt_bookname.Text.Length != 0 && txt_edition.Text.Length != 0)
    {
        btnsearchbooknameedition();
    }
    else if (txt_subcategory.Text.Length != 0 && txt_category.Text.Length == 0 && txt_author.Text.Length != 0 && txt_publisher.Text.Length == 0 && txt_isbn.Text.Length == 0 && txt_bookname.Text.Length == 0 && txt_edition.Text.Length == 0)
    {

        btnsearchsubcatauthor();
    }
    else if (txt_subcategory.Text.Length != 0 && txt_category.Text.Length == 0 && txt_author.Text.Length == 0 && txt_publisher.Text.Length != 0 && txt_isbn.Text.Length == 0 && txt_bookname.Text.Length == 0 && txt_edition.Text.Length == 0)
    {

        fillgridsubcatpublisher();
    }
    else if (txt_subcategory.Text.Length == 0 && txt_category.Text.Length == 0 && txt_author.Text.Length == 0 && txt_publisher.Text.Length == 0 && txt_isbn.Text.Length == 0 && txt_bookname.Text.Length != 0 && txt_edition.Text.Length == 0)
    {

        btnsearchname();
    }
    else
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
        Guid.NewGuid().ToString
        (), "<script language=JavaScript>alert('Fill The TextBox ');</script>");
    }
}
```

Comment: [This answer might help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2784140/187697)

Comment: Follow this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765815/asp-net-button-event-handlers-do-not-fire-on-the-first-click-but-on-the-second) , it will guide you in right direction. Hope it helps for you.

Comment: Are you sure you're not doing something odd in the `Load` method of the form? See, if the button were to change at all during the `Load` it could prevent the `Click` from firing. ASP.NET rebuilds the form server-side **before** firing events.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
1.set in congif file

```
 <System.web><pages eventvalidation="true"/></system.web>
```

2 take a look at `ValidationGroup` may be you need set correct value

But these as versions of your problem