# Dynamically added button on dynamically created button click event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button which is created from a MySQL query result. It looks like this:

1 Product name |add to basket|

And when I press the "add to basket" button, the product appears in a table on the right side(basket). Like this:

1 Product name |remove|

But for some reason, the `remove` button click-event removes all items from basket. When I press `add to basket` again, all items appear in the basket again.

This is whole class. Thank you for your help

```
public partial class neworder : System.Web.UI.Page
{   
    Basket basket;
    Table BasketTable;
    private int countRows = 0;
    private string distance;
    private string categories;
    ArrayList categoryList = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList productList = new ArrayList();
    private string products = "";


    public string Products
    {
        get { return products; }
        set { products = value; }
    }

    public string Categories
    {
        get { return categories; }
        set { categories = value; }
    }
    public string Distance
    {
        get { return distance; }
        set { distance = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
    }
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            basket = new Basket();
            Session["basket"] = basket;

        }
        populateCategories();
        populateProducts();
        loadBasket(); // if this is comment then i items are added fine 
//to basket but cant be remove, if its not commented then i can add 
//only 2 items in basket
    }

    private void populateCategories()
    {
        using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(Static.MysqlServer1))
        {
            cn.Open();
            String strSQL = "SELECT category_name FROM categories;";
            MySqlCommand cmdPLT = new MySqlCommand(strSQL, cn);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            myReader = cmdPLT.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                string cat = myReader.GetString(0);
                categoryList.Add(cat);
                categories += "<a href=\"#"+cat+"\">" + cat + "</a><br />";
            }
        }
    }
    private void populateProducts()
    {

        Panel1.Controls.Clear();
        string tem = "";
        foreach (string s in categoryList)
        {
            Table tableTitle = new Table();
            TableRow row1 = new TableRow();
            tableTitle.ID = s + "Title";
            tableTitle.CssClass = "rest2";
            Panel1.Controls.Add(tableTitle);

            TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
            Label label2 = new Label();
            label2.Text = "<a name="+s+">"+s+"</a>";
            label2.ID = "TitleText_" + s;
            cell2.Controls.Add(label2);
            row1.Cells.Add(cell2);
            tableTitle.Controls.Add(row1);

            Table table = new Table();
            table.ID = s;
            table.CssClass = "rest";
            Panel1.Controls.Add(table);

            using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(Static.MysqlServer1))
            {
                string name = "";
                string size = "";
                int id = -1;
                double price = 0.0;
                cn.Open();
                String strSQL = "SELECT product_id, product_name, product_price, product_size FROM products join categories on categories.CATEGORY_ID = products.CATEGORY_ID where category_name ='" + s + "' order by product_order asc;";
                MySqlCommand cmdPLT = new MySqlCommand(strSQL, cn);
                MySqlDataReader myReader;
                myReader = cmdPLT.ExecuteReader();
                while (myReader.Read())
                {                   
                    name = (string)myReader["product_name"];
                    id = (int)myReader["product_id"];
                    size = (string)myReader["product_size"];
                    price = (double)myReader["product_price"];
                    productList.Add(new Products(id, name, size, price));
                    GenerateRow(s, name, size, price, table, id);
                }
                if (!tem.Equals(""))
                {
                    tem += "</table>";
                }
            }
            products += tem;
            tem = "";
        }

    }
    private void GenerateRow(string category, string name, string size, double price, Table table,int id )
    {

            TableRow row1 = new TableRow();

            //ROW 1 NAME
            TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
            Label label1 = new Label();
            label1.Text = name;
            cell1.Style.Add("width", "300px !important");
            label1.ID = "NameText_" + category+id;
            cell1.Controls.Add(label1);
            row1.Cells.Add(cell1);

            //ROW 2 Size
            TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
            Label label2 = new Label();
            cell2.Style.Add("width", "100px !important");
            label2.Text = size;
            label2.ID = "SizeText_" +category+ id;
            cell2.Controls.Add(label2);
            row1.Cells.Add(cell2);

            //ROW 1 PRICE
            TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
            Label label3 = new Label();
            cell3.Style.Add("width", "60px !important");
            label3.Text = "" + price;
            label3.ID = "Price_" + category + id;
            cell3.Controls.Add(label3);
            row1.Cells.Add(cell3);

            //ROW 1 BUTTON
            TableCell cell4 = new TableCell();
            cell4.Style.Add("height", "25px !important");
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Text = "+";
            button.Click += button_Click;
            button.ID = ""+id;
            cell4.Controls.Add(button);
            row1.Cells.Add(cell4);
            table.Controls.Add(row1);
        }

    private void loadBasket()
    {
            Basket temp = (Basket)Session["basket"];
            BasketTable = new Table();
            BasketTable.ID = "basket";
            BasketTable.CssClass = "rest";
            PanelBasket.Controls.Clear();
            PanelBasket.Controls.Add(BasketTable);


        foreach (Products p in temp.ProductList)
        {

            TableRow row1 = new TableRow();

            //ROW 1 NAME
            TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
            Label label1 = new Label();
            label1.Text = p.Name;
            cell1.Style.Add("width", "100px !important");
            label1.ID = p.Name;
            cell1.Controls.Add(label1);
            row1.Cells.Add(cell1);

            //ROW 2 Size
            TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
            Label label2 = new Label();
            cell2.Style.Add("width", "40px !important");
            label2.Text = p.Size;
            label2.ID = p.Size;
            cell2.Controls.Add(label2);
            row1.Cells.Add(cell2);

            //ROW 1 PRICE
            TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
            Label label3 = new Label();
            cell3.Style.Add("width", "60px !important");
            label3.Text = p.Price+"";
            label3.ID = p.Price + "";
            cell3.Controls.Add(label3);
            row1.Cells.Add(cell3);

            //ROW 1 BUTTON
            TableCell cell4 = new TableCell();
            cell4.Style.Add("height", "25px !important");
            Button remove = new Button();
            remove.Text = "-";
            remove.Click += new EventHandler(button99_Click);
            remove.ID = "remove" + p.Id;
            cell4.Controls.Add(remove);
            row1.Cells.Add(cell4);

           BasketTable.Controls.Add(row1);
        }
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        string buttonId = button.ID;
        foreach (Products p in productList)
        {
            if (p.Id == Convert.ToInt32(buttonId))
            {
                Basket temp = (Basket)Session["basket"];
                temp.addPruduct(p);
                Session["basket"] = temp;
                    loadBasket();
                Label1.Text = temp.ProductList.Count + "";
            }
        }
    }
    protected void remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also share your `remove_Click` code.

Comment: How do you add the removeButton to the page? The one you declare seems not to be used at all

Comment: there is more code, I add it in to table. It does display correctly just not firing event

Comment: Clean up and share the rest of your code with us so we can see everything that is going on, tentatively it looks correct at first glance

Comment: You need to recreate the button on PostBack. So in `Page_Load` or `Page_Init` you need to call `loadBasket()`.

Comment: I have tried to call loadBasket() in there but event fires only once and also after two clicks buttons "add to basket" stops working.

Comment: Help me just a bit in understanding your code: The button created in the loadBasket() method is never added to your rendered page. Is that intentional?

Comment: You need to create [Minimal, **Complete** and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You don't have enough info here.

Comment: please have a look at updated post with code

Comment: Make sure you are assigning IDs to buttons. See some other common issues here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765815/asp-net-button-event-handlers-do-not-fire-on-the-first-click-but-on-the-second?rq=1

Comment: I also can see that not only dynamically created button doesnt fire event but also normal button created in aspx file does not fire event method. It happens after i press "add to basket" button twice