# Not saving after clicking the Add button once. I have to click the button twice to save it

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a problem on saving the data that I'm inputting. I have to click the button twice for it to fire up.

I'm trying to add the employee's group details. When I first click the Add button the group details that I'm adding will be successfully added but when i try to add another one again it will not be saved and I have to click the button again for it to be saved or for the button to function.

Here's the codes when I click the Add button

```
 If ValidateGroup() = "" Then

        taskoption = Request.QueryString("opt")

        If taskoption = "opt_edit" Then
            SaveGroup()
            disp_Details()
            Loadgv()
            Me.btnUpdate.Enabled = True
            Me.btnSave.Enabled = False
        ElseIf taskoption = "opt_add" Then
            disp_Blank()
            Me.btnSave.Enabled = True
            Me.btnUpdate.Enabled = False
        ElseIf taskoption = "opt_ae" Then
            SaveGroup()
            disp_Details()
            gvGroup.Visible = True
            tblGroup.Visible = True
            id_tm1.Visible = True
            tblAddGrp.Visible = True
            trgd.Visible = False
            disp_Group()
            Loadgv()
            Me.btnUpdate.Enabled = True
            Me.btnSave.Enabled = False
        End If
    Else
        Me.MessageBox("alert('Please complete the following: \n" + ValidateGroup() + "\n')")
    End If
```

here's my code in Page_Load

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    userid = getUserid(SessionHandler.UserID, User.Identity.Name.ToUpper(), username)
    bol_Admin = isAdmin(userid)
    bol_GlobalHR = isGlobalHR(userid)
    bol_RegionalHR = isRegionalHR(userid)
    bol_LocalHR = isLocalHR(userid)
    userEntity = getEntity(userid)
    userLocation = getLocation(userid)
    userRegion = getRegion(userid)

    If KnownUser(userid) Then
        If bol_Admin Or bol_GlobalHR Or bol_RegionalHR Or bol_LocalHR Then
            If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
                Dim win_id As String = User.Identity.Name
                loadSetup()

                If bol_Admin Or bol_GlobalHR Then
                    access = "GLOBAL"
                    ehr_utils.fillDDL("SELECT REGION FROM REGION_TBL ORDER BY REGION", ddl_Region, "REGION", "REGION")
                    ehr_utils.fillDDL("SELECT COUNTRY FROM COUNTRY_TBL ORDER BY COUNTRY", ddl_Country, "COUNTRY", "COUNTRY")
                    ehr_utils.fillDDL("SELECT ENTITY FROM ENTITY_TBL ORDER BY ENTITY", Me.ddl_Entity, "ENTITY", "ENTITY")
                    ehr_utils.fillDDL("SELECT LOCATION FROM LOCATION_TBL ORDER BY LOCATION", ddl_Location, "LOCATION", "LOCATION")
                    ehr_utils.fillDDL("SELECT DISTINCT C_PERIOD FROM PERIODSETUP_TBL", Me.ddl_period, "C_PERIOD", "C_PERIOD")
                    ehr_utils.fillDDL("SELECT SUBLOOKUP_NAME FROM SUBLOOKUP_TBL WHERE LOOKUP_NAME = 'YEAR'", Me.ddl_year, "SUBLOOKUP_NAME", "SUBLOOKUP_NAME")
                ElseIf bol_RegionalHR Then
                    access = "REGIONAL"
                    ehr_utils.fillDDL("SELECT REGION FROM REGION_TBL where region = '" & userRegion & "' ORDER BY REGION", ddl_Region, "REGION", "REGION")
                    ehr_utils.fillDDL("SELECT COUNTRY FROM COUNTRY_TBL where region = '" & userRegion & "' ORDER BY COUNTRY", ddl_Country, "COUNTRY", "COUNTRY")
                    ehr_utils.fillDDL("SELECT ENTITY FROM ENTITY_TBL where region = '" & userRegion & "' ORDER BY ENTITY", Me.ddl_Entity, "ENTITY", "ENTITY")
                    ehr_utils.fillDDL("SELECT LOCATION FROM LOCATION_TBL where region = '" & userRegion & "' ORDER BY LOCATION", ddl_Location, "LOCATION", "LOCATION")
                    ehr_utils.fillDDL("SELECT DISTINCT C_PERIOD FROM PERIODSETUP_TBL", Me.ddl_period, "C_PERIOD", "C_PERIOD")
                    ehr_utils.fillDDL("SELECT SUBLOOKUP_NAME FROM SUBLOOKUP_TBL WHERE LOOKUP_NAME = 'YEAR'", Me.ddl_year, "SUBLOOKUP_NAME", "SUBLOOKUP_NAME")
                ElseIf bol_LocalHR Then
                    access = "LOCAL"
                    Dim emp_id As String = Request.QueryString("emp_id")
                    selectedEmpEntity = getValueString("SELECT entity FROM EMP_MASTERTBL WHERE MASTERID = '" & emp_id & "'")

                    ehr_utils.fillDDL("SELECT REGION FROM REGION_TBL where region = '" & userRegion & "' ORDER BY REGION", ddl_Region, "REGION", "REGION")
                    ehr_utils.fillDDL("SELECT COUNTRY FROM COUNTRY_TBL where region = '" & userRegion & "' ORDER BY COUNTRY", ddl_Country, "COUNTRY", "COUNTRY")
                    'ehr_utils.fillDDL("SELECT ENTITY FROM ENTITY_TBL where entity = '" & userEntity & "' ORDER BY ENTITY", Me.ddl_Entity, "ENTITY", "ENTITY")
                    ehr_utils.fillDDL("SELECT ENTITY FROM LOCALHR_TBL WHERE USERID = '" & userid & "' ORDER BY ENTITY", Me.ddl_Entity, "ENTITY", "ENTITY")
                    ehr_utils.fillDDL("SELECT LOCATION FROM LOCATION_TBL where entity = '" & selectedEmpEntity & "' ORDER BY LOCATION", ddl_Location, "LOCATION", "LOCATION")
                    ehr_utils.fillDDL("SELECT DISTINCT C_PERIOD FROM PERIODSETUP_TBL", Me.ddl_period, "C_PERIOD", "C_PERIOD")
                    ehr_utils.fillDDL("SELECT SUBLOOKUP_NAME FROM SUBLOOKUP_TBL WHERE LOOKUP_NAME = 'YEAR'", Me.ddl_year, "SUBLOOKUP_NAME", "SUBLOOKUP_NAME")
                End If

                taskoption = Request.QueryString("opt")
                updateBtnRmndr.Visible = False

                If taskoption = "opt_edit" Then
                    gvGroup.Columns(9).Visible = True
                    gvGroup.Columns(10).Visible = True
                    disp_Details()
                    Loadgv()
                    loadSetup()
                    gvGroup.Visible = True
                    tblAddGrp.Visible = True
                    trgd.Visible = False
                    Me.btnUpdate.Enabled = True
                    Me.btnSave.Enabled = False
                    Me.ddl_BusinessUnit.Enabled = True
                    Me.ddl_SubClassification.Enabled = True
                    ehr_utils.fillDDL("SELECT BUSINESS_UNIT FROM BUSINESS_UNIT_TBL  ORDER BY BUSINESS_UNIT", Me.ddl_BusinessUnit, "BUSINESS_UNIT", "BUSINESS_UNIT")

                    'Check if the user has access to use the UPDATE ALL function
                    hasAccess = CheckRecord("SELECT * FROM ACCESSLIST_TBL WHERE MODULE_ID = '1' AND ACCESS = '" & access & "'")

                    If hasAccess Then 'allowed to use the UPDATE ALL function
                        btnUpdateHistoryRecord.Visible = True
                        btnUpdateHistoryRecord.Enabled = True
                        Session("originalEmpNo") = lblval_Empno.Text
                        updateBtnRmndr.Visible = True
                    Else ' Not allowed to use the UPDATE ALL function
                        btnUpdateHistoryRecord.Visible = False
                        btnUpdateHistoryRecord.Enabled = False
                    End If

                ElseIf taskoption = "opt_ae" Then
                    gvGroup.Columns(9).Visible = False
                    gvGroup.Columns(10).Visible = False
                    gvGroup.Columns(7).Visible = False
                    trgd.Visible = True
                    tblAddGrp.Visible = True
                    Loadgv()
                    disp_Details()
                    disp_Group()
                    gvGroup.Visible = False
                    tblGroup.Visible = False
                    id_tm1.Visible = False
                    Me.btnUpdate.Enabled = True
                    Me.btnSave.Enabled = False
                    'Check if the user has access to use the UPDATE ALL function
                    hasAccess = CheckRecord("SELECT * FROM ACCESSLIST_TBL WHERE MODULE_ID = '1' AND ACCESS = '" & access & "'")

                    If hasAccess Then 'allowed to use the UPDATE ALL function
                        btnUpdateHistoryRecord.Visible = True
                        btnUpdateHistoryRecord.Enabled = True
                        updateBtnRmndr.Visible = True
                        Session("originalEmpNo") = lblval_Empno.Text
                    Else ' Not allowed to use the UPDATE ALL function
                        btnUpdateHistoryRecord.Visible = False
                        btnUpdateHistoryRecord.Enabled = False
                    End If

                    Me.ddl_BusinessUnit.Enabled = True
                    Me.ddl_SubClassification.Enabled = True
                    ehr_utils.fillDDL("SELECT BUSINESS_UNIT FROM BUSINESS_UNIT_TBL  ORDER BY BUSINESS_UNIT", Me.ddl_BusinessUnit, "BUSINESS_UNIT", "BUSINESS_UNIT")

                ElseIf taskoption = "opt_add" Then
                    tblAddGrp.Visible = False
                    tblGroup.Visible = False
                    id_tm1.Visible = False
                    trgd.Visible = False
                    gvGroup.Visible = False
                    disp_Blank()
                    loadSetup()
                    Me.btnSave.Enabled = True
                    Me.btnUpdate.Enabled = False
                    'hide the UPDATE ALL function
                    btnUpdateHistoryRecord.Visible = False
                    btnUpdateHistoryRecord.Enabled = False
                End If
                div_birthDate.InnerText = txtBdate.Text
                div_entryDate.InnerText = txtEdate.Text
            Else
                Dim scriptString As New StringBuilder
                scriptString.Append("<script language=JavaScript>")
                scriptString.Append("alert('You are not allowed to view this page.');")
                scriptString.Append("window.location = 'eHR_Main.aspx';")
                scriptString.Append("</script>")

                If Not ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("Startup") Then
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(Page), "Startup", scriptString.ToString())
                End If
            End If

        Else
            MessageBox("alert('You're not allowed to view this page.');window.location='eHR_Main.aspx';")
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: what is the taskoption value on first and second click?

Comment: taskoption value on first and second click is "opt_edit"

Comment: Have u tried adding breakpoint to see if each function under `taskoption = "opt_edit"` is executed as expected? Since we can't tell what's inside those functions, it's either you need to post the full source code or use breakpoint and go line by line to find out the issue

Comment: I already use breakpoint when I click the button once it never goes to the codes then when I click it again it functions.

Comment: clicking once it does not post back but clicking twice runs the method?

Comment: yes @fofik I think it's in my Page_Load codes but I can't find a solution for it.

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765815/asp-net-button-event-handlers-do-not-fire-on-the-first-click-but-on-the-second