# Button click twice issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am having a simple webform where on load event i m binding data in gridview and then **i am having a search field where user search for particular record but button needs to clicked twice to get the result**. I am having add and delete button on my page but it does not need to be clicked twice.
Please let me know the issue.

This is my page_load event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        uname = (string)(Session["username"]);            
        BtnUpdate.Enabled = false;
        BindDropDown();
        BindGrid();
    }
}
```

This is my search function.

```
    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       DataTable dt1 = BindGrid();
       DataView dv = new DataView(dt1);
       string SearchExpression = null;
       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtsearch.Text))
       {
           SearchExpression = string.Format("'{0}'",txtsearch.Text.Trim());
           dt1.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Convert(FLAG_CODE, 'System.String') LIKE '" + txtsearch.Text + "%'";
           grdDetails.DataSource = dt1;
           grdDetails.DataBind();
           int count = grdDetails.Rows.Count;
           lblRecordsCount.Text = count.ToString();
       }
       else
       {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('Please enter flag code');", true);
       }
   }
```

aspx code

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Surviellance/Surveillance.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="GSMFlagMaster.aspx.cs" Inherits="Surviellance_GSMMaker" %>

   <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
   <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../Styles/style.css" type="text/css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Styles/StyleSheet.css" />


</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyContentPlaceHolder" runat="Server">
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="divContainermaster">
            <fieldset style="border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: 3px; border-color: #0071ad; height: auto">
                <legend style="background-color: #0071ad; border-radius: 10px; font-size: 14px; padding: 5px; color: white; font-family: open_sans_condensedbold,arail;"><b>GSM Master Details:</b></legend>
                <center>
                    <table style="width: 75%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tdtext">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblFlagCode" runat="server" Text="Flag Code"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxFlagCode" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td class="tdtext">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblEffectFrom" runat="server" Text="Effective from"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEffectiveFrom" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td class="tdtext">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblMonthTrade" runat="server" Text="Monthly Trading"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkMonthTrade" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="tdtext">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text="Status"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" ForeColor="White" Width="150px" BackColor="#0071ad">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="---select---" Selected="False">---Select---</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Active">Active</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Inactive">Inactive</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            <td class="tdtext">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblEffectTo" runat="server" Text="Effective to"></asp:Label></td>
                            <td class="auto-style3">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEffectiveTo" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td class="tdtext">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblWeekTrade" runat="server" Text="Weekly Trading"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkWeekTrade" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="tdtext">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblASD" runat="server" Text="ASD per"></asp:Label></td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlASDPer" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" ForeColor="White" Width="150px" BackColor="#0071ad">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="---select---" Selected="False">---Select---</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            <td class="tdtext">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblFlagDes" runat="server" Text="Flag Description"></asp:Label></td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxFlagDes" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" MaxLength="30" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td class="tdtext">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblTtoT" runat="server" Text="T to T Flag"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkTtoT" runat="server" Checked="True" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <br />
                    <table style="width: 75%; text-align: center">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="BtnAdd" class="button" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="BtnAdd_Click" />&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <asp:Button ID="BtnView" class="button" runat="server" Text="View" OnClick="BtnView_Click" />&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <asp:Button ID="BtnUpdate" class="button" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="BtnUpdate_Click" />&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <asp:Button ID="BtnClear" class="button" runat="server" Text="Clear" OnClick="BtnClear_Click" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </center>
            </fieldset>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />

            <fieldset style="border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: 3px; border-color: #0071ad;">
                <legend style="background-color: #0071ad; border-radius: 10px; font-size: 14px; padding: 7px; color: white; font-family: open_sans_condensedbold,arail;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblmemsearch" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Enter Flag Code"></asp:Label>&emsp;
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtsearch" placeholder="Enter Flag Code" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>                        
                    <asp:Button ID="BtnSearch" runat="server" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" Text="Search" />                        
                </legend>
                <br />
                <table style="float: right;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tdtext">No of Records:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblRecordsCount" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />
                <div style="width: 98%; height: auto;">
                    <asp:GridView ID="grdGSMMasterDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="true" ShowFooter="True"
                        Width="1400px" Height="12" ShowHeader="True" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Both" OnRowDataBound="grdGSMMasterDetails_RowDataBound" OnSorting="grdGSMMasterDetails_Sorting">
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#7779AF" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />

                        <Columns>....</columns

                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#016091" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" Font-Bold="True" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#ffccff" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#016091" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="white" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Check the properties of the SEARCH button.

Comment: this is my button '<asp:Button ID="BtnSearch" runat="server" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" Text="Search" />'

Comment: did you check if the btnSearch_Click event is firing when you click btnSearch once ?

Comment: No.Right click on the button and check its default properties.

Comment: Yes the event is firing, first the page_load is called on first click and then on second click btnSearch_click is called

Comment: @hameed the properties are same for all the buttons on the page

Comment: share your .aspx code? Have you used updatepanel?

Comment: @AnoopH.N yes i have used updatepanel

Comment: @abhishek suggestion would be to put debugger at the line DataTable dt1 = BindGrid(); and check whether it is hit for the first time.So if its not hit you need to check your update panel,designer page  and then Page_Load event.

Comment: no it is been hit forfirst time

Comment: Kindly check this link. This will solve your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765815/asp-net-button-event-handlers-do-not-fire-on-the-first-click-but-on-the-second

Comment: found the issue, the textbox was holding the autopostback property as true.